# Prolog: statement is true IFF it is true for all results

Tags: prolog

I've got the following facts:

```
fact_dataIsUsedFor(searchQueries, targetedAds).
fact_dataIsUsedFor(searchQueries, sendJunkMail).

fact_dataUsageIsUnfair(sendJunkMail).
fact_dataUsageIsFair(targetedAds).

fact_appStatesHowDataIsUsed(app, true).
```

I have a query here:

```
query_policyDataUseIsFair(App):-
    fact_dataIsUsedFor(_, DataUsePurpose),
    fact_dataUsageIsFair(DataUsePurpose),
    \+ fact_dataUsageIsUnfair(DataUsePurpose),
    fact_appStatesHowDataIsUsed(App, true).
```

What I'm trying to do is implement logic for which the statement is true if ALL of the answers to the above query return true, else a single false will make the statement return false.

Currently, this returns true for targetedAds, and false for sendJunkMail.

How would I go about getting it to return only 1 answer of true/false after evaluation of all results?

Thanks!

edit: Realised I didn't need a boolean flag on query_policyDataUseIsFair(App):- ...

edit 2: restructured question for clarity.

Comment: Could you please include a sample query you ran? Show exactly what results you get, and describe exactly what results you desire. When you say, *...this returns true for the first statement, ...* what "statement" are you referring to?

Comment: Sure thing. So when query_policyDataUseIsFair(App)/1 is run, it'll return true for targetedAds, as it should, and the next result will be false for sendJunkMail. What I want is for it to do it for both (and more, if there are more entries added later) to be evaluated as a batch, and the output to be a single true if ALL results evaluated are true, and false if even a single result is false. Hope that clears it up! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to undestand what do you want but I suppose you need `findall/3` and `forall/2`.

Something like

```
query_policyDataUseIsFair(App):-
    fact_appStatesHowDataIsUsed(App, true),
    findall(Dup, fact_dataIsUsedFor(_, Dup), List),
    forall(member(Elem, List), (fact_dataUsageIsFair(Elem),
                                \+ fact_dataUsageIsUnfair(Elem))).
```

`findall/3` is ISO Prolog but `forall/2` isn't; if your Prolog doesn't provide it (as my gprolog), you could implement it as follows

```
forall(Cond, Act) :-
    \+ (call(Cond), \+ call(Act)).
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was going for! Just to check my own understanding of this, we compose the query by using findall(X, statement(_, X), List) which will create a list of all results, then iterate over the results of the list with the checks that I've written. Is that correct?

Comment: @R.Sama - Correct. In the meantime I've slightly changed my answer: I've put in first position the check with `fact_appStatesHowDataIsUsed/2`. Maybe I'm wrong but I think it's more efficient because, if the check regarding `Act` fail, you avoid the check over all the `Dup`.

Comment: Thanks! You might be right there, and I see the logic behind it. Good shout.